# Ubuntu types... Need to fix win 7 from in my dual boot Mint 17.1. Read write screen of death

Tags: windows-7, grub, linux-mint, msconfig, read-write

Not sure what else to say. My Linux Mint knowledge is very peicemeal but i can do some scripting and have hacked my win 7 before from within Mint.

Am sure it can't be too hard to fix the memory problem: Win 7 : Tried to write to read only memory. It's hard to get the exact error as it keeps crashing from the blue screen.

Can't really tell you what I did before the problem as mainly just crashed and as my box doesn't have a reset button had to cut power. I think. Seemed so innocuous at the time wasn't really paying attention.

There's about 5 partitions on this box from the Grub Legacy I obviously didn't install them myself though.

Cheers, have tried a few things to find the Last Good Config etc but I don't know windows very well and guess it's quite a specific problem even though quite basic so haven't found the right fix.

Much obliged for any help.

{I'd like to correct that and say I don't know windows 7 very well. I know older solid win OSes quite well and could achieve some command line things a long time ago. I can also use terminal fairly well and have used several  linux OSes by now.}

Yes just did some more research and what most people are suggesting across the web will just kill my Grub Legacy set up and I'm not prepared to do this. - wednesday night edit

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-hardware/blue-screen-error-0x000000be/38a1fa7f-ccd9-4533-a12c-36c49d34831b?auth=1

Comment: Hi Michael, not sure which of the 7 answers you thought would help me. I have tried some of them, and like a couple of people say, it won't stay in windows long enough to do anything from in there.

Comment: If so you have to boot from Windows media and repair it. There's nothing you can do from Linux. And you shouldn't anyway. Actually, one of those "hackings" is likely to be the cause.

Comment: No not at all Michael. I cracked my admin password 6 months ago from in Linux, am sorry you are unaware of that aspect. No unusual things were done to windows except move photos and videos to and from the desk top.

Comment: Am guessing there may not be that many Ubuntu types on this forum.

Comment: Actually I use Ubuntu 99,9% of the time. There are lots of things you can do in a dual boot but not, for instance, perform error correction on NTFS partitions. And there are things that you can do but shouldn't like accessing the Windows system drive (especially in any Win8/8.1/10) from the other OS, one mistake is enough to render Windows unbootable. Insisting on a *solution from Linux Mint* is a X-Y problem and an unnecessary complication. Boot Windows media, repair (if possible), done. If everything else fails reinstall Windows and don't mess it afterwards.